# Timeout for Dropwizard's health checks?

Tags: java, dropwizard, jdbi

I have two sql database connections for which health checks are automatically added by dropwizard. But when the application loses connection to one of them, the /healthcheck endpoint takes indefinitely long to respond, where I would want it to timeout after a few seconds.

I've already set the `maxWaitForConnection` setting, and I've also experimented with the various `checkConnectionOn..` settings, but nothing helped.

UPDATE: The health check correctly fails if the server actively refuses the connection, but it hangs indefinitely if it's not the case, for instance, a network issue.

Is it possible to have sql health checks timeout at a specified time value whatever the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the JDBC timeout settings aren't working you could always just wrap the DB check in a [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and limit how long it can run:

```java
protected Result check() throws Exception {
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  Future<Void> future = executor.submit(new DbConnectionChecker());

  try {
    future.get(SECONDS_THRESHOLD, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  } catch (TimeoutException e) {
    return Result.unhealthy("DB timed out");
  }
  executor.shutdownNow();
  return Result.healthy();
}
```

Where `DbConnectionChecker` is something like:

```
static class DbConnectionChecker implements Callable<Void> {
  public Void call() throws Exception {
    // Check your DB connection as you normally would
  }
}
```

Would be nice to figure out why the JDBC connection settings aren't working as expected, though.

Comment: What you propose works great, so I think I'll implement this solution. I'll keep the question open for a little longer, in case someone comes up with with something else.

Comment: Might be worth adding details about your particular JDBC driver and version. Maybe it's a known problem.